# Point azure hosted root domain to aws classic load balancer

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I'm need to point an Azure hosted root domain/naked domain (example.com) to an AWS Elastic Load Balancer. Classic ELB's don't have IP's while A records can only point to IP's. Azure doesn't support the non-standard ALIAS/ANAME records that allow a CNAME-like configuration for A records.

Azure DNS provides a way to point to Azure cloud hosted websites using a combination of pointing the A record to the website's IP and creating a TXT record containing the DNS name of the website.

AWS Route 53 provides the ALIAS record type for connecting root domains to Load Balancers.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to using an extra server instance with a static (elastic) IP address just to do 301 redirects to www.example.com?

EDIT:I should add that since asking this question I found out that AWS network load balancers support both static and elastic IPs but we are on OpsWorks Chef 11 stacks which only supports classic load balancers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure doesn't support the non-standard ALIAS/ANAME records

Note that these are not non-standard records, because they aren't record types at all.  They are configuration entries that allow the nameservers to generate and return a standard A or AAAA record (or other standard types, in Route 53) based on information obtained dynamically by the nameserver, rather than based on static configuration.

But, there isn't another good solution to this. That's why these options exist.

A workaround is to use a service like http://wwwizer.com.

But your easiest and most straightforward solution is to host the domain on Route 53.  This doesn't require changing your registrar -- you only have to change the authoritative nameservers.  If you have subdomains that need their DNS hosted elsewhere for operational reasons, you can always delegate them.  But this is a limitation of the fundamental design of DNS.